# Get env-entry in scala jax-ws web-service

Tags: scala, soap, jax-ws

I'm implementing a quick and dirty SOAP web-service, using jax-ws and Scala.
I have a trait for endpoint interface and a class implementing that trait.
Everything was fine until I tried to get evn-entries from web.xml

I do something like that:
In web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>name</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>value</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

In code:

```
val context = new InitialContext().asInstanceOf[Context]
val value = context.lookup("java:comp/env/name")
```

I get `NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to specify a class for initial context factory in the property "java.naming.factory.initial". You can specify that in a HashTable object and pass it to InitialContext.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  
    "your initial context factory class name here");

val context = new InitialContext(env)
```